# Can't get John Gruber's web URL regex to work with c++ std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, std

I'm trying to use c++ `std::regex` to validate a URL.  Using an abbreviated form of John Gruber's web URL matching regex documented [here](https://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) (I just shortened the list of TLDs it will accept), `std::regex()` throws an exception with code 0x0e (which I believe is a syntax error)

```
std::regex myRegEx(R"((?i)\b((?:https?:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil)\b/?(?!@))))")
```

Note I'm using a c++11 raw string to avoid the need to escape the backslashes.

I'm guessing the c++ regex engine expects a different syntax than what John's expression uses, but I don't know enough to figure out how to adapt it.

What can I do to make this regular expression work with `std::regex`?

Comment: Hello. It should the inline modifier `(?i)`. Please see the marked question. If it didn't solve your problem then edit accordingly.

Comment: @revo:  That was it.   Move your comment to an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Also, I disagree that this should be closed as a duplicate because it's a different question and might help others trying to use the Gruber expression in c++ (the other answer would not turn up in a search unless you already knew what the problem was)

Comment: It's a matter of engine. `std::regex` uses ECMAScript which doesn't support inline modifiers. So if someone doesn't know the syntax and engine that `std::regex` uses it doesn't make sense for them. For this reason I added another dupe to the list. Also perhaps if we just leave "John Grubber" in body and remove it from title and modify title in a way that it clearly asks for a syntax problem it would be better.